# Installing fasd on Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-linux

I've been having trouble finding info on how to install a utility library like `fasd` on amazon linux.

https://github.com/clvv/fasd

I have found repositories for SUSE, RHEL, and other `yum` based distros. But being a bit of a newb to amazon linux, I'm not sure if there is a parallel to those distros for getting this on Amazon Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the instruction from ArchLinux AUR https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=fasd-git

It looks like you can just clone the repo (https://github.com/clvv/fasd) and do a `make install`.